# SELECT COUNT ... WHERE ... in SharePoint List

Tags: list, sharepoint-2010, count

I got some really big lists where I need Counts from specific queries without collecting the data.

In SQL it would be something like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable WHERE column1Value=536;
```

As CAML does not seem to have any possibilities to do that, how would you achieve that goal with a standard SharePoint List.

To be clear: I do NOT want to collect all corresponding items and then do a count on them

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a similar question, [Determine Total Count Of Items Returned By SPQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031998/determine-total-count-of-items-returned-by-spquery), it is not possible to get a count without selecting the items.