# Sharepoint: Total count of filtered list via webservices

Tags: web-services, list, sharepoint, count

In SharePoint 2013 I use a webservice to query a list:

`System.Xml.XmlNode node = myservice.GetListItems(listName, viewName, query, viewFields, rowLimit, queryOptions, null);`

I use CAML to apply filters to the default view and to limit the rows returned.

This works fine; now I want to get the total count of items with this particular filter setting how do I get this?

I know I can use `GetList` method but this returns me the total number of all items in the list w/o any filter applied.

Any idea to get the total count of list that is filtered via webservices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint has no equivalent of a `COUNT` function within a query; if you want anything besides the total item count, your only option is to execute the filtered query then count the number of items returned back.

Similar question from SP2010 (unfortunately the CAML spec hasn't changed in this regard in SP2013): [Determine Total Count Of Items Returned By SPQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031998/determine-total-count-of-items-returned-by-spquery)

Reference code from SharePoint.stackexchange: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26150/is-it-possible-to-return-only-the-count-of-the-query

Comment: Thanks for you answer... it is a pitty that SharePoint does not provide such _basic_ features :(

Comment: Agreed - if you're creating a solution that will be high volume though, with a regular need for such reporting, you may want to consider a design pattern in which you use Event Receivers to update say a SQL table that tracks each list item's ID & any other columns you need for analysis. This way, you can build & run reports off of the synced SQL table and not the SharePoint list directly.